# JDK dateformatter parsing DayOfWeek in German locale, java8 vs java9

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, java-9

I have tried some code in Java 8 (1.8.0_77) and Java 9 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode))

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eee", Locale.GERMAN);
DayOfWeek mo = dtf.parse("Mo", DayOfWeek::from);
System.out.println("mo = " + mo);
```

I am not too familiar with details of those classes, but in Java 8 this works, printing:

> mo = MONDAY

In Java 9, however it fails

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mo' could not be parsed at index 0
>       at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
>       at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1890)
>       at day.main(day.java:10)

Any ideas, is this reproducible?

so, when formating:
using this code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eee", Locale.GERMAN);
String format = dtf.format(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
System.out.println("format = " + format);
```

jdk1.8.0-77:

> format = Mo

jdk-9 (build 9+181)

> format = Mo.

Comment: https://ideone.com/6t60j1 Are you sure about java-8?

Comment: well I used 1.8.0_77. is it possible to use this version on this site?

Comment: Ideone is providing some version you have no control over it. (and the service is already really nice IMHO)

Comment: @Tom You have misinterpreted the javadoc. "eee" is text abbreviation in format style (not stand-alone like "ccc").

Comment: @MenoHochschild Ok then. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I can acknowledge that OPs code works on Java 8 (1.8.0_131).

Comment: @RC I'm using JDK 1.8.0_144 and it works. Didn't test with JDK 9, though.

Comment: Have you tried your first code with "Mo." in Java 9? Does that work? If yes, then it looks like the abbreviation has been changed?

Comment: @Tom: yes with "Mo." it works in JDK 9. Anyway, this seems to be a breaking change then. Well or maybe there is some standard which rules that "Mo." is the correct version so that was changed...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be there in [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) due to the current implementation of [CLDR date-time-patterns](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time-patterns) with the implementation of [JEP - 252](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) which states that

> Use locale data from the Unicode Consortium's Common Locale Data
> Repository (CLDR) by default.
>
> Localized patterns for the formatting and translation of display
> strings, such as the locale name, may be different in some locales.
>
> To enable behavior compatible with JDK 8, set the system
> property `java.locale.providers` to a value with *COMPAT ahead of CLDR*.

---

And to second the data part of it, the [international components for Unicode in **German locale**](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=de) which has the following relevant information can justify that *the behavior is intentional* -

[image]

***Edit/Note***: As linked in the comments, the [migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-AFD3BDEC-99FC-4F3C-946F-A1CD2D05B74B) states a similar warning for such implementations -

> If your application starts successfully, look carefully at your tests
> and ensure that the behavior is the same as on JDK 8. For example, a
> few early adopters have noticed that their dates and currencies are
> formatted differently. See [Use CLDR Locale Data by Default.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-A20F2989-BFA9-482D-8618-6CBB4BAAE310)

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-AFD3BDEC-99FC-4F3C-946F-A1CD2D05B74B

"If your application starts successfully, look carefully at your tests and ensure that the behavior is the same as on JDK 8. For example, a few early adopters have noticed that their dates and currencies are formatted differently. See Use CLDR Locale Data by Default."

Answer (score 9):

The abbreviatiions "Mo", "Di" etc. without dot have not disappeared in CLDR but are accessible via standalone-mode. **You should change your pattern using the standalone format symbol "c" instead of "e"**:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ccc", Locale.GERMAN);
DayOfWeek mo = dtf.parse("Mo", DayOfWeek::from);
```

Indeed, I consider the change of underlying data as breaking backwards compatibility (concrete as behavioural break).

Comment: The transition to using CDLR locale data by default is indeed a disruptive change. JDK 8 includes the CDLR locale data so you can run with `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR` to identify any issues in advance of moving to JDK 9.