# Literal dash added to DateTimeFormatterBuilder causes parsing to fail

Tags: java, java-9, java-time

I'm trying to create a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to match the following example (it's actually slightly more complex than this but that shouldn't matter).

```
20180302-17:45:21
```

I've written the following but it results in an exception:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .toFormatter()
    .parse("20180302-17:45:21");
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20180302-17:45:21' could not be parsed at index 11
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1816)
```

It appears to be failing on the colon between `17:45` and [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendLiteral`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendLiteral-char-) doesn't give any clues.

If I change the literal to another character, let's say `m`, then it works fine:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('m')
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .toFormatter()
    .parse("20180302m17:45:21");
```

What's going on here? How can I fix it, assuming I can't change the format?

Comments suggest this might be version dependent. I'm using JDK 9.0.1 and it's [been reproduced on 9.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109551/literal-dash-added-to-datetimeformatterbuilder-causes-parsing-to-fail?noredirect=1#comment85224962_49109551).

Comment: umm, using your code, i get the output `{},ISO resolved to 2018-03-02T17:45:21` and not an error

Comment: yeah that might be it. still using java 8

Comment: Are you sure the character you're appending is the same one as in the example snippet ([hyphen-minus](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)), and not for example [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)?

Comment: Can confirm, it works with Java 8 and fails with Java 9 (without recompiling).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm certain. And anyway, the given index of the failure doesn't correspond to the position of the dash.

Comment: I have reproduced the exception on Java 9.0.4. On Java 1.8.0_131 I don’t see it.

Comment: `.append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)` seems to be part of the problem. If I replace it by `.appendPattern("uuuuMMdd")`, parsing works also on Java 9.0.4.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the [offset ID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#getId--), which expects a zone offset id in the format `+hhmm` or `-hhmm`. Therefore, an exception is thrown because BASIC_ISO_DATE tries to parse `-17:` as a zone offset id.

Comment: Agreed, but the offset ID does have a colon. It is not the colon that is causing the problem, but the '4' after the colon. There is no time zone in the world which is offset from UTC by hh:4x.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException It think there are countries in the world having an offset of *n* hours and 45 minutes difference with UTC.

Comment: You're right. The documentation for [BASIC_ISO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE) says that it takes an offset and explicitly states "without colons".

Comment: I get a strong feeling about this also being related to the [CLDR date-time patterns changes in JDK9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245412/1746118)

Comment: @Michael What if you replace `BASIC_ISO_DATE` with `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`?

Comment: @MCEmperor That works but I'm parsing text I have no control over the format of.

Comment: @Michael So you only have control over the string passed to `parse` (e.g. `parse("20180302-17:45:21")`)? In that case, your only option is to add the zone offset to the date, such that the pattern is still valid: `20180302Z-17:45:21`

Comment: @MCEmperor The other way around. I can't control the input. I've worked around the issue for now by using a similar solution to the `appendPattern("uuuuMMdd")` suggested by Ole

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments elsewhere!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has got to do with the fact that `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` includes an optional offset ID. Apparently your formatter parses `-17` as an offset and then objects because there is a colon where the format requires a hyphen.

When you use `m` instead, this cannot be parsed as an offset and therefore matches the literal `m` in the format, and everything works.

I tried using uppercase `Z`. `Z` can be an offset ID too.

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('Z')
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .toFormatter()
    .parse("20180302Z17:45:21");
```

Now I got `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20180302Z17:45:21' could not be parsed at index 9`. Index 9 us right after the `Z`, so it seems the formatter parses the offset and then tries to find the literal `Z` where the `17` is.

EDIT: And the solution? Instead of using `BASIC_ISO_DATE` append a pattern:

```
.appendPattern("uuuuMMdd")
```

Now parsing works also on Java 9.0.4.

EDIT: Further to illustrate the optionality of the offset:

```
System.out.println(
    LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
);
System.out.println(
    OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
);
```

This printed

```
20180305
20180305+0100
```

So in the first case, where no offset is available, it just leaves it out. In the second case, where one is available, it is also printed (without colon).

Open question: Why does it work in Java 8? Is this really a bug?

Quote:

> - If the offset is not available to format or parse then the format is    complete.
> - The offset ID without colons. If the offset has seconds    then they will be handled even though this is not part of the    ISO-8601
>     standard. The offset parsing is lenient, which allows the    minutes
>     and seconds to be optional. Parsing is case insensitive.

From [the documentation of `BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE)

Comment: So why does BASIC_ISO_DATE, which specifically says it is "without an offset", even include an offset ID?

Comment: Regarding your second open question: `BASIC_ISO_DATE` states that It will try to parse "*The offset ID without colons*" and it must be in the format `±hhmm` or `±hhmmss`.

Comment: You are right, @Michael, that is funny. Strictly speaking it is correct since the offset ID is optional, but I might take it as misleading still.

Comment: Thanks, @MCEmperor. Next time I will read the quote I am pasting into the answer. :-)

Comment: @OleV.V. No problem. This is very interesting (and also difficult) matter, and without your question, I probably wouldn't have taken a further look at the documentation.

Comment: Probably related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066806 where more offset formats are handled in Java 9 as opposed to Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I raised this as a bug and it's been confirmed in [JDK-8199412](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8199412).