# Has conversion between Instant and Date changed from Java 8 to 11?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

When updating from Java 8 to 11 I noticed the following difference, which can break logical flow quite seriously:

Given the following code

```
final Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println(now.minusNanos(1).isBefore(now));
System.out.println(Date.from(now.minusNanos(1)).before(Date.from(now)));
```

Executed on **Java 8** (corretto 1.8.0_232) prints:

```
true
true
```

Contrary **Java 11** (corretto 11.0.0.5_10) prints:

```
true
false
```

So my Question is: Why exactly does this happen and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joda Date Time returns very different results between Java 8 vs Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199566/joda-date-time-returns-very-different-results-between-java-8-vs-java-11)

Answer (score 10):

What changed is the output of `Instant.now()`. From the documentation of [Clock](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eegahlin/jep-349/javadocs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC()):

> This clock is based on the best available system clock. This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), **or a higher resolution clock if one is available.**

[OpenJDK 11 uses a higher resolution clock](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730), and so returns an `Instant` with a nanosecond part. `Date` only has millisecond precision, so it implicitly truncates the Instant when converting between the two.

You can get equivalent behaviour in JDK 8 and 11 by calling `Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)`, or by using [Clock#tickMillis](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eegahlin/jep-349/javadocs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#tickMillis(java.time.ZoneId))