# Java String to Date format

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

I have below `String` of date that I'm trying to parse and format to `Sept 21 2021` but having `ParsingException`:

```java
String expiryDate ="Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021";
System.out.println(expiryDate);
Date formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(expiryDate);
```

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException:
Unparseable date: "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
```

I guess I have incorrect parsing date format but can't figure out the correct one.

Comment: I have compiled your code and it worked and the result of printing `formatter` is `Tue Sep 21 08:41:37 IRDT 2021` for me. I'm suing JDK 8. which JDK are you using?

Comment: @MortezaBandi I've tried to run the code in online compiler, it works with JDK 8 and doesn't with JDK 11. Edit: tried JDK 9 and 10, work in those too. It only doesn't work with 11.

Comment: Since your problem is a JDK related one, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049592/simpledateformat-format-gives-different-results-in-java8-vs-java11

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is the missing `Locale` in your `SimpleDateFormat`. If you don't explicitly set one, the code may use your default `Locale`, which then might not be `ENGLISH` but something else, which is likely to be on a computer located on the Philipines. It would try to parse the Philipine abbreviation for *Tue*, for example, and that leads to an unparseable `String`.

Here is what worked on my computer (also not `ENGLISH`) after having got the same `Exception` as you:

```java
String expiryDate = "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .parse(expiryDate);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

This gave the following output:

```
Tue Sep 21 06:11:37 CEST 2021
```

This worked with a pattern having just one `E` as well.

---

## Java 8 - 10 solution with `java.time`:

**This successfully runs on Java 8 and 10, but according to [the answer by @ArvindKumarAvinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333713/1712135), this won't work in Java 11 and possibly the versions above due to the abbreviation of the time zone in the `String expiryDate`.**

You could do it like this in `java.time`:

```java
String expiryDate = "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021";
DateTimeFormatter parserDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu",
                                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(expiryDate, parserDtf);
System.out.println("Something will expire at " + zdt);
```

and it would output

```
Something will expire at 2021-09-21T12:11:37+08:00[Asia/Manila]
```

Changing the output format can be done via another `DateTimeFormatter`, either use a built-in one as `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` or create a custom one by `.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH)` or using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Considering your requirement to format and output the date part only, you have the option to simply extract the date part (that's a `LocalDate`) and format that in `java.time`:

```java
String expiryDate = "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021";
DateTimeFormatter parserDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu",
                                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(expiryDate, parserDtf);
LocalDate expiryLocalDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
System.out.println("Something will expire at "
                    + expiryLocalDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu",
                                                                        Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

will output

```
Something will expire at Sep 21 2021
```

Read more about `java.time` in the [Trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Nice answer! Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64332848/10819573) is brilliant but that fails with Java-11. A safe option will be to replace PHT with the [corresponding Zone-Offset value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine_Standard_Time).

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expiryDate = "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021".replace("PHT", "GMT+08:00");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(expiryDate,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d H:m:s ZZZZ u", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        String formatted = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMMM dd uuuu 'at' hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-21T12:11:37+08:00
Tuesday September 21 2021 at 12:11:37 PM
```

**Note:** `java.util` date-time classes are outdated and error-prone and so is their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

If you are doing it for your Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**With legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String expiryDate = "Tue Sep 21 12:11:37 PHT 2021".replace("PHT", "GMT+08:00");
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy").parse(expiryDate);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Custom format
        String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here, sorry if I did anything wrong.

The "Tue" contains three character and the format should be

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

Comment: You just copied the String from the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for wanting to contribute. You don’t need three `E` in the format patter string to parse a three letter abbreviation (and in other languages than English the abbreviation may not be three letters long). [The documentation of the modern `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) says: *The text style is determined based on the number of pattern letters used. Less than 4 pattern letters will use the short form. …*

Comment: In case you insist on using the notoriously troublesome and long outdatded `SimpleDateFormat`, [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) say: *For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.*

Answer (score 0):

### The explanation

It seems that the abbrevatiosn for Philipines Standard Time was PHT up to Java 10 whereas it’s PST from Java 11. One way to see this is running the following piece of code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter zf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z", Locale.ROOT);
    ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila");
    System.out.println(zf.format(ZonedDateTime.now(zid)));
```

Output on Java 9:

> PHT

Output on Java 11:

> PST

I thought at first that different versions of CLDR, the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository, was the reason. But when I use Java’s original locale data instead (running with `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT`), I get the same difference in behaviuour, so I am not so sure.

In any case you should not rely in three letter time zone abbreviaitons in the first place if there is any way you can avoid it. They tend to be ambiguous, and they are not standardized. So you really cannot be sure what you get.

Apart from that the comments and answers telling you to specify a locale for your formatter are correct too.