# Time refresh in the console

Tags: java, time, console, refresh

I tried to program date and time so that it corresponds to the current date but could not find a solution in the console, only the date of the last run is displayed. Here is my code:

```
public class DateDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy 'um' HH:mm:ss ");
        System.out.println("Datum: " + ft.format(dNow));
    }
}
```

Comment: package test;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DateDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Date dNow = new Date( );
      SimpleDateFormat ft = 
      new SimpleDateFormat ("E dd.MM.yyyy 'um' HH:mm:ss ");

      System.out.println("Datum: " + ft.format(dNow));
      
    
   }
}

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use either `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` and in any case `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: So are you expecting the program to overwrite the previously printed line with the date and time continuously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consoles behave differently, so I’m afraid that there isn’t any universal solution.

I tried this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)
                    .withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    ZoneId timeZoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich");
    int totalIterations = Math.toIntExact(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(2));
    for (int sec = 0; sec < totalIterations; sec++) {
        System.out.print(ZonedDateTime.now(timeZoneId).format(formatter) + '\r');
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
```

When I run it inside Eclipse, it prints the lines under each other in the Eclipse console like this:

> ```
> 16. November 2019 07:37:32 MEZ
> 16. November 2019 07:37:33 MEZ
> 16. November 2019 07:37:34 MEZ
> 16. November 2019 07:37:35 MEZ
> ```

[image: Screen shot from Eclipse console]

But when I run it from the Terminal window on my Mac, it stays on the same line and just keeps overwriting it:

[image: Screen shot from Terminal]

The `\r`character is a *carriage return*. In theory it should go back to the beginning of the same line. Maybe the reason why it doesn’t in Eclipse is they thought I wanted to use the console window for debugging and therefore would be better served if I could see all output, so they didn’t want to overwrite any. Just guessing.

There are more elegant and more accurate ways to make something happen every second. Look into [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

PS The format differs a bit in the two screen shots, in the Terminal window `um` (“at”) is included between the date and the time. The difference comes from different Java versions. In Eclipse I used Java 8, in the Terminal window Java 11. The story is in this question: [JDK dateformatter parsing DayOfWeek in German locale, java8 vs java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244724/jdk-dateformatter-parsing-dayofweek-in-german-locale-java8-vs-java9).